# Errno 13 after script creates file

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to Python and have been working on a script to split a flat file into separate ones. The flat file is organized so that each line begins with a certain number, which correlates to a province.

I have created two lists, one for the number set, the other for the province. These are ordered appropriately so that the number matches up to the province.

I have also created nested loops. The first loop goes through each line of the file, the nested loop will match the number, and append the line into a file, which is named using the province list.

I keep getting Errno 13, permission denied, at line 17 ("with open(...") but it will happen during various iterations of the loop. Sometimes the second, third, fourth, etc. There shouldn't be any permissions issues with this file, as it's simply in a folder on my desktop.

TL;DR script is writing to new files in a loop, but will sometimes get a permissions error after creating the file.

```
import os

FileLocation = r'C:/Users/user/Desktop/FLAT File split tests/DLY44_INT_P2020'
SaveLocation = r'C:/Users/user/Desktop/FLAT File split tests/'

FileName = os.path.basename(FileLocation)
DType = FileName[0:5]
Year = FileName[-4:]

NumList = ['3','1','5','81','84','22', '25','82','23','24','6','83','7','4','21'] 
ProvList = ['AB', 'BC', 'MAN','NB','NFL','NWT1','NWT2','NS','NUN1','NUN2','ON','PEI','QC','SK','YUK']

with open(FileLocation,'r') as data_file:
        for line in data_file:
                for i,j in zip(NumList,ProvList):            
                        if line.startswith(i):
                            with open(SaveLocation+DType+'_'+j+'_'+Year, 'a+') as file:
                                file.write(line)
                                file.close()
```

Edit to add traceback (again, please note that it has happened for various files. So, this specific file is sometimes created successfully, but it will error on a different one):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\FLAT File split tests\Split National Flat Files.py", line 25, in <module>

    with open(SaveLocation+DType+'_'+j+'_'+Year, 'a+') as file:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/FLAT File split tests/DLY44_AB_2020'
```

Comment: The `file.close()` is superfluous. I would not be too surprised if taking that out actually fixed your problem, though I guess that's not what's going on here. Can you show a traceback?

Comment: Try executing this script from your terminal/command line with admin privelleges.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've also tried without file.close() and I have the same issue. I will post a traceback soon!

Also, I am unable to execute with admin privileges as it's a work computer.

Answer (score 0):

Following could be reasons

1. If you don't have sufficient permissions to that folder where you are creating the file
2. If you have already a folder with same name .(Suppose if the script is trying to create "sample.txt" file and if you have a folder with same name "sample.txt").
3. If you don't have enough space to create files.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

1. What's confusing is that it creates some of the files as it should, and then will error after creating 3 or 4. This is made more difficult as it's for work, and I do not have admin privileges. 

2. There is no folder with the same name, but that would make sense.

3. My computer says it has plenty of space. 

I did research the error quite heavily before posting here. I also sent the code and file to my colleague who experienced the same issue.